# Why is one of these question considered opinion-based, but the other is not?

Tags: discussion

[What is the difference between the horror and thriller genres?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67566/what-is-the-difference-between-the-horror-and-thriller-genres)

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67528/can-robot-movies-and-tv-shows-be-reduced-into-two-major-categories

Just want to get a clear understanding so I can avoid trouble in the future.

Comment: I can see why you are asking.  I think the horror and thriller genre question isn't opinion based as there are clear and well understood distinctions in these mainstream genres - for instance you will get serious academic study of them.  The other question someone is just proposing their own subgenres.

Comment: you lost me at electric sheep skynet

Comment: @DForck42 haha but seriously.  Analysis of material is one of the great strengths of this forum, limited perspectives notwithstanding.

Comment: @DukeZhou I hope my answer helps clarify the difference

Comment: @DForck42  It definitely clarifies why it is considered to be off topi, although I still don't find the distinctions valid.  (But I do appreciate your taking the time to comment!)

Answer (score 6):

**The essential difference is that one will have either one or a small set of answers, while the other one won't.**

---

The Robot movie categories question has several issues.

The first issue is that it takes a while to really get to the premise of the question.  It needs a good edit to clean it up.

The second issue is that the question seems to have already made up its mind as to what the actual answer is to the question by providing evidence for what is ultimately the answer it's looking for.

Also, the way the question is written is essentially asking for people to agree or disagree, and that's just opinion and is off-topic.

Another issue at large is that the question is trying to arbitrarily group ALL "robot" movies into two distinct groups, without clearly defining what a robot movie is or WHY we're grouping them together.

So, essentially, this question is trying to wrangle a broad spectrum of movies into two specific categories, which is going to be a highly debatable answer, and is better for discussion rather than a Q&A site.  The question also lacks citing any official sources for the discernment for these categories.

---

In comparison, the second question linked asking about the difference between two genres WILL have a relatively accurate set of answers as these are two distinct, well established genres.  They do have overlap, but there are defining differences between the two.

Comment: I appreciate your taking the time to comment, but your argument is flawed.  1.  The nature of the question requires context.  I'm happy nor to have non-readers ignore it. 2. I may have a position, with evidence to support, but the basis of the question is to seek *evidence based* challenge or confirmation.  3. The categorization is not arbitrary, but based on valid thematic analysis, similar to previous literary categorizations.

Comment: @DukeZhou this question HAS a thematic analysis, but it lacks a coherent question FOR that analysis